# How to implement the following scenario using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, blazemeter

Can anyone help me out how to implement the following scenario using Jmeter, in this scenario N number of users should be able to log in at once and implement the same scenario at the same time?

I have already tried using recording option but it is not updating in the database.

To some HTTP requests, it is showing ***SSO*** issue.

**Steps:**
1. Login to the web application.
2. A landing page is displayed.
3. Two options displayed.
4. Selecting one option, which will redirect to the specific landing page.
5. From home page, we will search for the products.
6. Selecting one product and it redirects to the customization page.
7. In the customization page, we are inputting the values, updating the changes to the order.
8. Finally completing the order with update changes in it.

Where the customize order will ask us to move into the cart or it will ask us to submit for approval.

Comment: You're talking about performance, not functional testing now, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

The solution basically depends on *what* you exactly testing.

Let's consider the application consists of single HTTP server (at least, in terms of endpoint) + single HTTP client (which doesn't reach different sources for data/services, especially with modern protocols like websocket).

Then each of your scenarios turns out to be a series of HTTP request/response interactions, whatever happens under the hood.

So the best way to lay it out for JMeter would be to record sample(s) of this interaction & parametrize it.

You can do it with JMeter itself (check, for example, [this guideline](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-jmeter-to-record-test-scenarios) or ["official" one](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)), or use other tools (like Fiddler) then implement the sequence in the JMeter.

But that is for more, say, "classic" web app, where client (browser) are pretty lightweight and mostly in charge of sending requests & rendering responses - while *most of the duties lays on server*, and **this** is that you going to test for performance.

For modern, web apps with responsibilities blurred & spread between server AND client (not to mention asyncronous interactions) that way may be good enough too - but may be NOT.

Then you'd may want to evaluate performance for app as a whole, in assembly. 
One of the way to achieve that in JMeter is to use WebDriver plugin for JMeter, [check this tutorial](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/).